Changes to Tor moderator team, and scheduling a moderator election
You may have noticed that some moderators on your site have lost their moderator access today. On July 8th, 2024, we released a new version of the moderator agreement. Moderators network-wide had 30 days to sign the new agreement. Of the 600 moderators network-wide, around 44 did not sign the new revision of the moderator agreement by the deadline. As a result, those 44 moderators’ diamonds were removed today.
While we are generally satisfied with this outcome, unfortunately some sites lost more moderators than others. On Tor, there is only one moderator remaining as of today.
We are currently in the process of scheduling new elections where needed, and we will prioritize sites like Tor that have been harder hit by this change. Until a new election concludes, Community Managers (Stack Exchange employees) will be checking on Tor occasionally to assist with moderation. However, please be aware that it may take a bit longer than normal for flags to be handled.
We would encourage you to begin discussing and organizing your community for an election, and we’ll be around to schedule one soon.
In the meantime, we strongly encourage curators to use site curation tools to the best of your ability (up/down voting, closing, editing, flagging, and reviewing), in order to provide a good experience for users of Tor in the interim. If you see anything that needs immediate staff attention, please feel free to contact us.
